# When scrolling flashing background color

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My code is to apply `div background-color` when user **touchstart** on each div. that's clear for you.

Then when user scrolling, I use `$(window).scroll`.. event to **reset** or **remove** background-color for all div's.

---

***But my problem is***: when user (**touch** + **scrolling**) at div's, ***background-color is flashing out color!*** I want to: don't change div background-color when (tap, touch + scrolling).
 if you don't understand my question, you can see: (facebook messenger friend conversations, snapchat conversations, stories ..etc)

Flashing div's:
[image]

My code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GLUIAUU64MDX - RUN ON TOUCH DEVICES.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  resetBg();
});

$(".❄").on('touchstart', function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "#7bffea");
});

$(".❄").on('touchend mouseleave mouseup blur click', function() {
  resetBg();
});

function resetBg() {
  $(".❄").css("background-color", "");
}
```

```css
div.❄ {
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="❄"></div>
  <div class="❄"></div>
  <div class="❄"></div>
  <div class="❄"></div>
  <div class="❄"></div>
  <div class="❄"></div>
  <div class="❄"></div>
  <div class="❄"></div>
  <div class="❄"></div>
  <div class="❄"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting background on `touchstart`, you can get the pointer position at `touchstart` and on `touchend` check if pointer position is changed or not. If not, change the div background and set a timeout function to reset it. If the position of pointer is changed then it's a scroll so you don't need to change the background

```
let initialY = null;

$(".❄").on('touchstart', function(e) {
  initialY = e.clientY;
});

$(".❄").on('touchend', function(e) {
  if(e.clientY===initialY){
     $(this).css("background-color", "#7bffea");
    setTimeout(()=>{    //This is optional
      resetBg();
    },100);
  }
});

function resetBg() {
  $(".❄").css("background-color", "");
}
```

Comment: Do you have and example? an code solution for me sir ?

Comment: Yeah, I added an example to the answer

Comment: 1. Always flashing when touchend after scrolling. 2. Remove that optional timeout, not working!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
resetBg();
});

 //----------------------------------------------

$(document).on('touchstart', '.❄', function(evt) {
var that = this;
var oldScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
window.setTimeout(function() {
    var newScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (Math.abs(oldScrollTop - newScrollTop) < 3) $(that).css("background-color", "#7bffea");
  }, 200);
});

 $(".❄").on('touchend touchmove mouseleave mouseup blur click', function() {
  resetBg();
 });

function resetBg() {
  $(".❄").css("background-color", "");
}
```